# WebView modal is buggy: navigation bar bg becomes translucent when scrolled to top, and toolbar when scrolled to bottom

Tags: ios, swift

I'm seeing the following weirdness in a non-SwiftUI iOS app. I've put a small, self-contained repro at the end.

---

I open a WKWebView inside a modal.

The navigation bar and toolbar are both set to `isTranslucent = false`.

Now I see two issues that go away if I remove the `…isTranslucent = false` lines:

1. When the modal loads and the page is scrolled to the top, the navigation bar has a transparent background, showing its icon against the red background of the root view.
2. When I scroll the page all the way to the bottom, the toolbar becomes transparent in the same way, showing its icon against the red background.

[image: GIF of repro]

Any ideas how to keep the nav bar and toolbar as non-translucent while avoiding this bug?

---

I'm not sure if all the issues mentioned in https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-ios/issues/150#issuecomment-449422224 (referenced in a code comment) are still relevant, but I did notice that if I don't make the toolbar translucent, it will overlay the bottom content of certain pages (such as https://auctionet.com/en/about, at the time of writing).

---

This is a single-file repro – you can generate a new iOS app in Xcode (Interface: Storyboard, not SwiftUI) and paste this in ViewController.swift and it should build.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        view.backgroundColor = .red
        self.presentModalWebViewController(for: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/compliance/")!, hideBrowserUI: false)
    }

    func presentModalWebViewController(for url: URL, hideBrowserUI: Bool) {
        let modalWebViewController = ModalWebViewController()
        modalWebViewController.load(url)

        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: modalWebViewController)

        navigationController.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)

        // Just to show that the thing at the bottom is indeed `toolbar`.
        navigationController.toolbar.barTintColor = .yellow

        // ------
        // This fixes initial scroll position issues and positioning issues caused by WKWebView bugs as described in https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-ios/issues/150#issuecomment-449422224

        // Commenting this out fixes the "nav bar is transparent when scrolled to top" issue.
        navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

        // Commenting this out fixes the "toolbar is transparent when scrolled to bottom" issue.
        // The background does change from yellow to white (in light mode) when we reach the bottom.
        // I can live with that since the yellow is just for debugging, but it's curious.
        navigationController.toolbar.isTranslucent = false

        // ------

        present(navigationController, animated: true)
    }
}


class ModalWebViewController: UIViewController {
    private lazy var webView: WKWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Just to have something in the nav bar and toolbar.
        setToolbarItems([ UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .organize, target: nil, action: nil) ], animated: false)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .organize, target: nil, action: nil)

        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(webView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        ])
    }

    func load(_ url: URL) {
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this (just before `present(navigationController, animated: true)`) fixed it:

```
navigationController.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
```

Or if you need to support iOS 12 or earlier:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    navigationController.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
} else {
    navigationController.view.backgroundColor = .white
}
```